# Send message in "when" section of "choice" to the next processor after "choice"

Tags: mule

I need to transform message in "when" section of "choice" and after that send message to the next processor after "choice". How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just do the transformation and the result of it will be used in the next message processor after choice.

Comment: Which transformer I should use (In "when" section I have used "cxf:jaxws-client")? And where (after "choice" or in "when")?

Comment: What transformation do you want to achieve? This will help deciding on the transformer. Where is based on whether you want the transformation to happen for all paths (after choice) or just for one (in when).